# Accessing authenticated php page from html and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, http, authentication

I am trying to write a simple html page to create a mashup of two data feeds.  One of the data feed sources is a PHP page that produces a Google Earth KMZ file each time it is requested.  My goal is to display this feed on a map on my page in 'real-time'.

The particular PHP page requires authentication and I have the username and password.  When I plug the URL into a web browser it asks for my credentials, I provide them and it downloads a KMZ file.

I would like to have my html page use javascript to make the HTTP Request to the PHP page, retrieve the returned KMZ and load it on the map.

I am completely new to this sort of thing, so please let me know if I'm headed in the right direction and is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify *which type* of authentication is being used on the remote side, hence, I'm going to make some guesses and assumptions:

**Basic HTTP Authentication**

If "[Basic HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)" is used (Which would show a browser pop-up requesting username/password for the realm), you can formulate your request URL as follows:

```
http://username:password@host.name/file.name?parameter=x
```

Where:

- `username` is your actual known username
- `password` the actual password
- `host.name` the address of the remote server,
- `file.name` the PHP file you are trying to access
- **optional:** `parameter=x` any known parameters required to get the required output from the PHP file

**PHP Authentication**

If the actual authentication is done by the PHP page itself it's a different story. In that case it all depends on which variables the PHP script uses to perform authentication, specifically which *type* of parameter. Most commonly `GET` or `POST` are used (or if `REQUEST` is used, both will work).

Either way, you will have to know the name of the parameter that is being used. I'm going to assume `user` and `pass` for the examples below.

In the PHP script these will look like `$_GET['user']`, `$_POST['user']`, `$_REQUEST['user']` or simply `$user` if the dangerous [register_globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is set in `php.ini`.

In case of `GET` or `REQUEST`:

```
http://host.name/file.name?user=username&pass=password&parameter=x
```

In case of `POST`:

It is possible to `POST` values using JavaScript. [This SO answer gives a working examle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/813718)

**Anything else**

If any other method (and there are plenty others) is used, more specific information is required to determine the exact method and a working solution.

Comment: Thanks @Remco - I'm not sure what type of authentication is used.  I tried both methods you described and it still gave me a pop up asking for username and password.  The first method first told me that I was attempting to log into a site that does not require authentication.  Could this be because the domain itself does not require authentication, but the php page does?